# How to create .docx writer from scratch with Python?

Tags: python, xml, pdf-generation, docx, python-docx

My end goal is to create a very basic docx writer from scratch, as I am unhappy with the current python library offerings.

Can someone point me to some good references, or how to get started with a very stripped down "create your own" docx writer that can simply create a text box and write to a docx file.

Note, I am not asking for library recommendations. I want to implement my own tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won´t be an easy task, specially if you want to start from scratch, you may get an idea here

https://docs.fileformat.com/word-processing/docx/

You may want to read the DOCX standard directly from Microsoft

https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-DOCX/%5bMS-DOCX%5d.pdf

And the OpenOffice documentation

http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML.php

Comment: oof yeah I just learned about how a word doc is basically all these XML Files... I may have to give this one a miss for now